# The ratio of true vs. false hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics

I am currently reading a paper [Why Most Published Research Findings Are False](http://journals.plos.org/plosmedicine/article?id=10.1371/journal.pmed.0020124), which claims that many findings published in research papers are actually false.

In the introduction the author defines the following:
*Let R be the ratio of the number of "true relationships" to "no relationships" among those tested in the field.* (Relationships referring to/being used synonymously used for hypothesis).

Later he postulates that *the pre-study probability of a relationship being true is R/(R +1)*.

I am wondering why the probability of a relationship tested to be true (pre-study) should be *R/R-1*?
Shouldn't it be *true relationships/(true + no relationships)*?

Comment: Let $T$ be the number of true relationships and $N$ the number of no relationships.  Then $R = T/N$.  Try substituting $T/N$ for $R$ in $R/(R+1)$ and see if you can simplify...

Comment: @Heinrich , is *R/R-1* a typo ?

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @jbowman is correct:

Let $T$ be the number of true relationships and $N$ the number of no relationships. Then $R = T/N$. Try substituting $T/N$ for $R$ in $R/(R+1)$ and see if you can simplify...